# PHP Fatal Error while uploading/resizing images

Tags: php, file-upload, resize-image

I'm using a code which will upload an image, put the image in the "resize" folder, resize the image, move the image into another folder, then delete the image from the "resize" folder, however I'm getting the following error:

"**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14172 bytes) in /home/photogra/public_html/administrator/components/com_gallery/admin.gallery.php on line 649**"

The images aren't even big! (eg. 265kb)

Here's the code I'm using (with the line numbers):

```
635         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$mainframe->getCfg( 'absolute_path' ) ."/virtualgallery/images/resize/$newname");
636         
637         /* resize images - width 600px */   
638         $docRoot = $GLOBALS['mosConfig_absolute_path'];
639         $pathToImages = $docRoot.'/virtualgallery/images/resize/';
640         $pathToThumbs = $docRoot.'/virtualgallery/images/';
641         $thumbHeight = 600;
642         
643         $dir = opendir( $pathToImages );
644         while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) {
645             $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
646             if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) {
647                 $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
648                 $width = imagesx( $img );
649                 $height = imagesy( $img );
650                 $new_width = floor( $width * ( $thumbHeight / $height ) );
651                 $new_height = $thumbHeight;
652                 $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
653                 imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
654                 imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
655             };
656         };
657         closedir( $dir );
658         
659         /* delete file(s) from resize folder */
660         $dir = $docRoot.'/virtualgallery/images/resize/';
661         foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v) {
662             unlink($v);
663         };
```

Also when I get that error, images are getting stuck in the "resize" folder.. If anyone can help, that'd be fantastic! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to resize all the images in a directory without freeing the memory after each one. Try adding

```
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($tmp_img);
```

For starters. Also, unlink the image as soon as you're done with it rather than iterating over the directory a second time.